# call a code behind function from jquery in aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to call a codebehind function from jquery.

The aspx file name is group_master.aspx

The jquery is

```
    function populatecontrol(list, control) {
    var id = 0;
var GroupName=document.getElementById('<%=hdnGroupNameCheck.ClientID %>');
if (list.length > 0) {
    $.each(list, function (key, value) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(value);
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnGroupNameCheck.ClientID %>').value=obj.Second;
        control.html("Group already exist").append('<a id="editclick" href ="edit('+obj.Second+')">Click here to edit or enquire</a>');


    });
}
else
control.text="Group does not exist"
}
```

The edit('+obj.Second+') is an edit function in codebehind.

Thanks,

Comment: I know pagemethod but the same method is used for various other buttons.Can't it be called using some server tag or something

Comment: If it's a common function, you could implement it in a base page class from which your pages would derive; though, there are probably more clever ways to handle it.

Comment: You can wrap call to that method in web method and still use it in other buttons.

Comment: You could also create a web service, and use jQuery to call it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an ideal candidate for `Page Methods`. See this tutorial for more details:

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make code behind method static and also need to mark it as [WebMethod] so that it will get treated as service method and then uisng jQuery ajax call you can call code behind method like:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
      url: loc + "/GetMessage",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

    })
    .success(function (response) {
      alert(response.d);

    })
    .error(function (response) {
      alert(response.d);
    });
```

Get complete example here : http://www.codegateway.com/2012/05/jquery-call-page-codebehind-method.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of page methods.  In short, you would create a web method in your code behind which would be called by your jQuery logic.

See this link for an example: [Page methods in asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/12/24/page-methods-in-asp-net.aspx)